# how to check value in previous week

Tags: sql

I have table having values for week by week, I need to select another column to show value for previous week.

```
Select Week, Value, PreviousWeek'svalue from Data
```

```
Week  Value     Previous WeeksValue 

Week1   11  
Week2   13           11
Week3   46           13
Week4   10           46
Week5   15           10
```

Comment: Please explain your `previous` values for 4th and 5th weeks.

Comment: updated values now, thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  *
       ,lag(Value) over(order by Week) as Previous_Weeks_Value
from    t
```

| Week | Value | Previous_Weeks_Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Week1 | 11 | null |
| Week2 | 13 | 11 |
| Week3 | 46 | 13 |
| Week4 | 10 | 46 |
| Week5 | 15 | 10 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mU4Xi7yQ)

Comment: `select t.*, ...` would make this more portable, and ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: You may want to add ta note hat your code (*obviously helpful to OP*) would work only with SQL implementations that support `Window Functions`.